# Como faço para o video do POP-UP pare ao fechar a janela da pagina?

Tags: html, css, popup

Bom, eu não tenho muito experiência em HTML, jÁ tentei e não consigo fazer com que o video pare de ser reproduzido ao fechar a janela do POP-UP.

Se alguém puder ajudar ou dar uma dica agradeço.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    /** Donna Galletta | LIGHTBOX MARKUP **/
    
    .lightbox {
      /** Default lightbox to hidden */
      display: none;
      /** Position and style */
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    
    .lightbox:target {
      /** Remove default browser outline */
      outline: none;
      /** Unhide lightbox **/
      display: block;
    }
    /** videoModal **/
    
    #videoModal {
      border-radius: 0;
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    #videoModal .modal-header {
      background: #000;
      border: 0;
      color: #fff;
      position: relative;
      height: 35px;
    }
    
    #videoModal .modal-header h3 {
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 22px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    #videoModal .modal-body {
      height: 489px;
      padding: 0;
      max-height: none;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #videoModal .modal-footer:empty {
      display: none !important;
    }
    
    #videoModal .close {
      background: #DB00B8;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 24px;
      margin: 0;
      opacity: 1;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      text-shadow: none;
      top: 0;
      width: 38px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- thumbnail wrapped in a link -->
  <a href="#img1">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50535826153_58450a4c61_o.png" height="30">
  </a>

  <!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->
  <div>
    <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
      <div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close full-height" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
          <h3>Donna Galletta- Showreel</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"><iframe width="100%" height="489" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SvuoDerqNW0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
        <div class="modal-footer"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá! Para fazer o vídeo parar é necessário incluir a API do player do Youtube e chamar a função `stopVideo()` via javascript.

No link do vídeo no iframe é necessário acrescentar o parâmetro `enablejsapi=1`. Também acrescentei um `id="player"` apenas para facilitar a chamada no javascript.

```
<iframe id="player" width="100%" height="489" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g0O9XwWFa54?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
```

Depois você precisa chamar o script do frame API:

```
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

e criar o script para manipular o player:

```
<script>
    var player;
    
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player');
    }
    
    document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function(){
      player.stopVideo();
    });
</script>
```

Ficou assim no final:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    /** Donna Galletta | LIGHTBOX MARKUP **/
    
    .lightbox {
      /** Default lightbox to hidden */
      display: none;
      /** Position and style */
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }
    
    .lightbox:target {
      /** Remove default browser outline */
      outline: none;
      /** Unhide lightbox **/
      display: block;
    }
    /** videoModal **/
    
    #videoModal {
      border-radius: 0;
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    #videoModal .modal-header {
      background: #000;
      border: 0;
      color: #fff;
      position: relative;
      height: 35px;
    }
    
    #videoModal .modal-header h3 {
      font-size: 18px;
      line-height: 22px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    
    #videoModal .modal-body {
      height: 489px;
      padding: 0;
      max-height: none;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #videoModal .modal-footer:empty {
      display: none !important;
    }
    
    #videoModal .close {
      background: #DB00B8;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 24px;
      margin: 0;
      opacity: 1;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      text-shadow: none;
      top: 0;
      width: 38px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- thumbnail wrapped in a link -->
  <a href="#img1">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50535826153_58450a4c61_o.png" height="30">
  </a>

  <!-- lightbox container hidden with CSS -->
  <div>
    <a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="img1">
      <div id="videoModal" class="modal hide fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="videoModalLabel" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close full-height" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
          <h3>Donna Galletta- Showreel</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"><iframe id="player" width="100%" height="489" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g0O9XwWFa54?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
        <div class="modal-footer"></div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

    <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    
    <script>
        var player;
        
    //cria o player com base no iframe existente
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
          player = new YT.Player('player');
        }
        
    //captura clique no botão fechar e para o vídeo
        document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function(){
          player.stopVideo();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Abraço!

Comment: Mas seu eu tiver algo assim, como que faço?                                
 <video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Comment: Nesse caso, dentro do script, vc pode apagar a parte de criação do player e substituir o `player.stopVideo();` dentro do evento de clique por `var media = document.querySelector("#player"); media.pause(); media.currentTime = 0;`. E acrescentar também um `id="player"` na tag <video>

Comment: Valeu! Obrigado pela ajuda! Funcionou pra mim!